# Erro ao executar SQL "Create Trigger..." dentro de uma aplicação C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, trigger, create

Objetivo: Rodar um script de create trigger usando uma string dentro do C#.

Problema1: Tabela não encontrada (pois o script não indica em qual Tabela criar o trigger).

Tentativa2: Começar a string com "Create Trigger  on [Banco].[dbo].[Tabela]".

Problema2: Para criação de Trigger o SQL não permite pré-nomear o Banco.

Tentativa3: Começar a string com " Use [Banco]
                                  GO
                                  Create Trigger..."

Problema3: O comando "Create Trigger" deve ser sempre o primeiro do script. Além disto ele não consegue interpretar o comando GO, pois não é nativo do SQL.

Não tenho outra opção, tentei fazer via stored procedure, os mesmos problemas ocorrem.
Por favor, alguém já enfrentou esse problema antes?
Grato.

```
    strSql = "      CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_ALERTA]           ";
                    strSql += " ON [dbo].[Alertas_Integracao]           ";
                    strSql += "     after INSERT            ";
                    strSql += "     AS          ";
                    strSql += " If (SELECT Defeito FROM INSERTED) = 1   ";
                    strSql += "         begin       ";
                    strSql += "     BEGIN           ";
                    strSql += "         DECLARE     ";
                    strSql += "         @EQUIPAMENTO_ID int,        ";
                    strSql += "         @SETOR_ID   int,    ";
                    strSql += "         @PROBLEMA int,      ";
                    strSql += "         @INTEQUIPAMENTO int,        ";
                    strSql += "         @STRALERTA varchar(max),        ";
                    strSql += "         @IDEVENTO int       ";
                    strSql += " select @INTEQUIPAMENTO = Equipamento from Inserted      ";
                    strSql += "         select @STRALERTA = Alerta from Inserted        ";
                    strSql += "         select @EQUIPAMENTO_ID = (SELECT ieq_equ_equipamentos_id        ";
                    strSql += "         from EQU_IEQ_INTEGRACAO_EQUIPAMENTOS        ";
                    strSql += "         where ieq_equipamento_integrado =  @INTEQUIPAMENTO)     ";
                    strSql += "         select @SETOR_ID = (Select equ_sto_setores_id       ";
                    strSql += "         from EQU_EQU_EQUIPAMENTOS       ";
                    strSql += "         where equ_equipamentos_id = @EQUIPAMENTO_ID)        ";
                    strSql += "         select @PROBLEMA = (Select prb_problemas_id     ";
                    strSql += "         from EVE_PRB_PROBLEMAS      ";
                    strSql += "         where prb_descricao = @STRALERTA        ";
                    strSql += "         and prb_equ_equipamentos_id = @EQUIPAMENTO_ID)      ";
                    strSql += "         insert into EVE_EVE_EVENTOS     ";
                    strSql += "         (eve_usu_usuarios_id,       ";
                    strSql += "         eve_sto_setores_id,     ";
                    strSql += "         eve_sta_status_id,      ";
                    strSql += "         eve_data_inclusao,      ";
                    strSql += "         eve_problema,       ";
                    strSql += "         eve_corretiva,      ";
                    strSql += "         eve_equ_equipamentos_id,        ";
                    strSql += "         eve_inativo,        ";
                    strSql += "         eve_prb_problemas_id)       ";
                    strSql += "         values      ";
                    strSql += "         (2,     ";
                    strSql += "         @SETOR_ID,      ";
                    strSql += "         6,      ";
                    strSql += "         GETDATE(),      ";
                    strSql += "         @STRALERTA,     ";
                    strSql += "         1,      ";
                    strSql += "         @EQUIPAMENTO_ID,        ";
                    strSql += "         0,      ";
                    strSql += "         @PROBLEMA       ";
                    strSql += "         )       ";
                    strSql += "         SELECT @IDEVENTO = @@IDENTITY       ";
                    strSql += "         insert into EVE_SEV_STATUS_EVENTOS      ";
                    strSql += "         values (@IDEVENTO, 6, getdate())        ";
                    strSql += "     END         ";
                    strSql += "     end         ";  

clsCon.ExecutarSql(strSql);
```

Comment: Coloca os fontes na pergunta!

Answer (score 0):

Fiz assim e funcionou, veja se te atende.
Uma dica é tentar simplificar o seu comando (no caso a trigger) para garantir que o problema não esta ali.

Criei as Tabelas abaixo:

```
create table [dbo].TB_TESTE(
 id int identity ,
 nome varchar(100),
 idade int
)

create table [dbo].TB_TESTE_HIST(
 id int identity ,
 nome varchar(100),
 [Data] datetime
)
```

E criei o seguinte console application:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string MyTrigger =
@"CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_Exemplo_UPD] ON [dbo].[TB_TESTE]
    AFTER UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if(UPDATE([IDADE]))
    BEGIN

        Declare @nome VARCHAR(100);
        select @nome = nome from inserted ;
        insert into [dbo].TB_TESTE_HIST ([Nome], [Data]) values (@nome, getdate());

    END;    
  END;";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cnx = "Server=localhost; Database=Dev-Test; Trusted_Connection = false; User Id=sa; Password =XXXX; Persist Security Info=true; MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            var cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cnx);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(MyTrigger, cnn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O Resultado final foi a trigger criada no banco de dados:

[image: Trigger Criada]

Comment: Fiz e deu certo. Obrigado, José Diz!